# How do I get a python program to remain active on the server after I close putty?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssh, putty, bottle

I wrote a program a few months ago in python/JavaScript that uses bottle, but when I moved it to my website (hosted on Amazon Web Service), it works when I type: `sudo python2.7 moviegame.py`, but when I close Putty, the website doesn't show my game.

How do I get the server to keep running my program without relying on my computer?

Comment: Use `nohup` -> `nohup python my_code.py`

Comment: Or [`screen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html)

Comment: Is nohup the only way to do it? Is there something I can write into the actual python file that will do it? Or is nohup the only way the server will no to continuously run my code?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would use something like supervisor http://supervisord.org/ or some other process control system. There are many out there.